# scrolling text within a div

Tags: jquery, scroll

In a page I'm working on I have html container for a div height not more than
200px, however I need to fit in a text that requires 300px and I don't
want to show the scroll-bar on the right side so I'm looking for some
ways/plug-ins in order to scroll the text within the div. I'd like to
be able to scroll down, to scroll up and to stop the scrolling.

Any suggestions about?

Comment: I'm confused, you don't want a scroll bar, but you want to be able to scroll?  Does that mean you want another button for scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can highly recommend jQuery.ScrollTo.
It will fit your needs perfectly.

[Documentation is found here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

[Some demos are found here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

[And most importantly, here is the project page at plugins.jquery.com where the latest download is located](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the style overflow:auto for the div. To control scrolling only in Y, set overflow-y:auto, overflow-x:hidden

Answer (score 1):

Try [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) - I've used it and it works quite well.